# git diff: many patches with three '@' symbol

Tags: git, diff, git-diff, git-show

I am writing an automatic tool based on `git show`, which relies on `git diff` command. I wrote a small parser which takes the output of git show as the text to parse, and in most situations in the result the lines start with '@@' indicates which lines it will compare.

However, I met an situation like this:

```
@@@ -460,22 -415,8 +460,22 @@@
```

What does that mean? Is it possible that there will be even more (4 or more) '@' symbols with even more subtle meanings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are showing a merge in combined diff format. If you look at the man-page of `git show`, it has a complete section about `combined diff format`, when it is used and how it looks like. Also in the initial description of `git show` it says that merges will be shown like `git diff-tree --cc` which also refers to the combined diff format.

And yes, there can be more than three `@` symbols. There will be one per parent commit + 1. So if you have a merge with three parents (a so-called octupus merge), there will be four at signs. If you have four parents, there will be five at signs and so on.

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like you're doing a show on a merge, and this hunk differs from both parents; could that be the explanation?

Comment: Thanks a lot. Could you please offer me some detailed document explaining its output format or something else where you learned about this knowledge?

Comment: I wish I had detailed documentation; I guessed from the notation, then tested whether that was it in a toy repo.  I would expect that the only remaining wrinkle is if there's an octopus join; I don't know what the unified format does with that.

Comment: Just look at my answer and you will see that it is well documented, directly in the commands man page. ;-)

Comment: Why yes, how careless of me not to check your answer form 11 minutes ago before posting my comment 17 minutes ago

Comment: I didn't say or imply or intended to imply that you were careless. I just told you that you can find further information in my question and also that others who look at this answer and the comments may have a look at my question. No need to be offended. :-)